# How to access a List of Objects from outside a class in python

Tags: python, class, dictionary, object

Hope you can help me on this one.
I have created a list of objects because the program that I use creates lots of agents and it is easier to keep track.I want to access that information from outside the class, so I need to call that list and call in the agent number(which is created from the simulator).
I have put a simplified version so you can understand better.

This is the Main Class

```
from StoreCar import *
carObject  = []
class Machine:
   def calculation():
        VehicleID = 2 # this is genarated Austomatically from system 
#and increases every time a vehicle enters 
        Fuel = 15 # this is also calculated automatically from system.
        carObject.append(StoreCar(VehicleID,'car')
        carObject[VehicleID-1].setFC(Fuel)
```

This is the Class StoreCar which stores all the info

```
class StoreCar:
   def __init__(self, id_,name):
       self.id_ = id_
       self.name= name
       self.FCList= []

   def setFC(self,Fuel):
       self.FCList.append(Fuel)
```

This is the outside class that I want to access data from

```
 from Machine import *    
 class outsideclass:
    def getVehiData():
            # I want to access the data which was saved in Machine class from here.
```

Comment: What I want is to access data stored in Machine Class  (Vehicle data) from outsideclass. if I am not clear please let me know. thanks @LogicStuff

Comment: It's difficult to help you because it looks like you would need to learn more about OOP and re-think the whole scheme of your program. Moreover you should [create a simplified example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (but containing your main script) and avoid to talk about things that are not related to your question (for instance it looks like we don't need to know about context stuff like the agent number or the simulator...).

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually storing anything inside the `Machine` class. The only thing that you *are doing* is storing values in the (confusingly named) `carObject`:

```
from StoreCar import *
carObject  = []
class Machine:
   def calculation():
        VehicleID = 2 # this is genarated Austomatically from system 
#and increases every time a vehicle enters 
        Fuel = 15 # this is also calculated automatically from system.
        # You're putting things in the `carObject` *list*, which
        # should probably just be called `cars`
        carObject.append(StoreCar(VehicleID,'car')
        self.carObject[VehicleID-1].setFC(Fuel)
```

Your code, in general, has a few problems that is probably making your life more difficult that it needs to be right now, and will certainly make things worse down the road. I'm *assuming* that you're in some kind of class and this is homework given with some specific constraints because otherwise there is absolutely no reason to do a lot of the things that you're doing.

Here are the things I'm changing:

- `from <module> import *` is *very* rarely what you want to do. Just `import module`. Or, `import super_long_annoying_to_type_module as slattm` and use dot access.
- You don't *need* a `Machine` class, unless that's one of the parameters of your assignment. It's not doing anything except cluttering up your code. `calculation` doesn't even take `self`, so either it should be decorated with `@classmethod`, or just be a function.
- Python naming conventions - modules (files), variables, and functions/methods should be `snake_cased`, classes should be `StudlyCased`. This won't kill you, but it's a convention that you'll see in most other Python code, and if you follow it will make your code easier to read by other Python programmers.

**cars.py**

```
class StoreCar:
   def __init__(self, id_,name):
       self.id_ = id_
       self.name= name
       self.fc_list= []

   # If you're *setting* the fuel capacity, it shouldn't be a list.
   # (assuming that's what FC stands for)
   def add_fuel(self, fuel):
       self.fc_list.append(fuel)
```

**factory.py**

```
import cars

class Machine:
   def __init__(self):
       self.cars = []
       # Assuming that the vehicle ID shouldn't 
       # be public knowledge. It can still be got
       # from outside the class, but it's more difficult now
       self.__vehicle_id = 0

   def calculation(self):
        self.__vehicle_id += 1
        fuel = 15 # this is also calculated automatically from system.
        car = cars.StoreCar(self.__vehicle_id, 'car')
        # Typically, I'd actually have `fuel` as a parameter
        # for the constructor, i.e.
        #    cars.StoreCar(self.__vehicle_id, 'car', fuel)
        car.add_fuel(fuel)
        self.cars.append(car)
```

**somethingelse.py**

```
 import factory

 class SomeOtherClass:
    def get_vehicle_data(self):
        machine = factory.Machine()
        machine.calculate()
        print(machine.cars)
```

Note, that if I were unconstrained by any kind of assignment, I would probably just do something like this:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Car = namedtuple('Car', ('id', 'fuel_capacity', 'name'))


def gen_vehicle_ids():
    id = 0
    while True:
        id += 1
        yield id

vehicle_id = gen_vehicle_ids()


def build_car():
    return Car(id=next(vehicle_id), name='car', fuel_capacity=15)
    # If you don't want a namedtuple, you *could* just
    # use a dict instead
    return {'id': next(vehicle_id), 'type': 'car', 'fuel_capacity': 15}

cars = []
for _ in range(20): # build 20 cars
    cars.append(build_car())

# an alternative approach, use a list comprehension
cars = [build_car() for _ in range(20)]

print(cars)   # or do whatever you want with them.
```

For a comparison between what you can do with the namedtuple approach vs. dict approach:

```
# dict approach
for car in cars:
    print('Car(id={}, name={}, fuel_capacity={})'.format(
          car['id'], car['name'], car['fuel_capacity']))

# namedtuple approach
for car in cars:
    print('Car(id={}, name={}, fuel_capacity{})'.format(
          car.id, car.name, car.fuel_capacity))
```

<sub><sup>Check out http://pyformat.info for more string formatting tricks.</sup></sub>

Comment: Couldn't you replace `gen_vehicle_ids():` with `itertools.count()` ?

Comment: @TerrenceBrannon yes. The OP mentioned that the ids were generated, though, so if they're not sequential then a generator would work better. But you're right, if they're just sequential then `itertools.count()` would be a better choice.

Comment: @WayneWerner Thanks for the well explained answer. The reason that I used Machine class is to avoid confusion, but it seems that it makes the question more confusing. I am using a vehicle trajectory simulator, so the API in the simulator will act as the Machine class. since it is an simulator it generate car numbers and Fuel consumption values. What I wanted to do Is to save Fuel consumption values with the car ID. so when I want I can call the VehicleID and get the Fuel Consumption values, from an outside class.

Comment: or can I use a d]ictionary to store data and access it

Comment: Ah, `fuel_consumption`, that makes more sense to have an array that way. Honestly, I would start with just a dictionary that was something like `cars = {'42': {'id': 42, 'name': 'car', 'fuel_consumption': [12.0, 13.3, 15.2]}}`. If that gets too cumbersome, then I'd change things up to use a class. But start simple.